# Form submit function being repeated each time it is called

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a datatables page with a bootstrap modal dialog as the edit page. When the user submits the form, it repeats all the `submit()` actions that it has performed since the page loaded. Well, it repeats part of them.

This is the function that gets called when someone edits a row of the table. `selectedRow` is a datatables row

```js
function showEditDialog(selectedRow){
    var selectedRowData = selectedRow.data();
    var selectedRowIndex = selectedRow.index();
    console.log("showing dialog " + selectedRow.index());
    $("#editTitle").text(selectedRowData[0]);
    for(var col = 0; col < columnDefinitions.length; col++){
        //columnDefinitions is an array with metadata about each column
        // jquery wouldn't work for some reason
        document.getElementById(columnDefinitions[col].columnName + "_input").value = selectedRowData[col];
    }

    $("#modalEditDialog").modal();
    var frm = $('#editForm');
    frm.submit(function(event){
        console.log("submit " + selectedRowIndex);
        event.preventDefault();
        var theData = frm.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: theData,
            success: function(theReply){
                console.log(theReply);
            },
            error: function(xhr, desc, err){
                alert(err);
            }
        });
        var formInputs = $("#modalEditDialog :input[id$=input]");
        for (var i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++){
            theTable.cell(selectedRowIndex, i).data(formInputs[i].value);
        }
        $("#modalEditDialog").modal('hide');
    });
}
```

When the form is called the selected row's data is copied into the inputs, and then the submit function copies the updated data from the form back to the selected row in the table, as well as updating it on the server.

It all works hunky dory, except for the fact that whenever it gets called it remembers all the times it was called, and refreshes the table rows from the last times as well, except that it refreshes them with the current data in the form.

If I look at the console log I see this:

```
//first time I hit the edit button
showing dialog 1428        tapeDB:183:17
submit 1428                tapeDB:193:21
updated 1428  successfully tapeDB:203:29 //from update.php

//next time I hit the edit button:
showing dialog 1427        tapeDB:183:17
submit 1428                tapeDB:193:21 //WTF?
submit 1427                tapeDB:193:21
updated 1427  successfully tapeDB:203:29 //from update.php
```

And it's cumulative, so if I call it again it applies to three rows and so on. At first I thought it wasn't doing the ajax call as well, but it probably is, only since the info from the form is sent the server only updates one row.

Here's how I call the edit dialog (`daataa` is my table):

```
$("#daataa tbody").on('dblclick', 'tr', function(){
    showEditDialog(theTable.row("#"+this.id));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the reason is that I have a pretty basic misunderstanding of javascript. When I attach the function to the submit button it is attached each time the form is shown, meaning that a new copy of the function is attached each time. I fixed it by removing the function from any previous instances like so:

```
var frm = $('#editForm');
frm.off("submit"); //detach any existing submits.
frm.submit(function(event){…
```